# Частица НЕ с прилагательным

Tags: орфография, частица-не

На сайте "Грамота.ру" размещены интерактивные диктанты. Я попробовал один из них "написать" - и получил "красную карточку" за то, что в предложении "... в привычках той эпохи,  незнакомой с нашим понятием о плагиате..." слово "незнакомой" я написал слитно. Сайт выдал справку, что частица НЕ с причастием пишется раздельно, если имеется пояснительное слово. Но разве "незнакомой" - это причастие?

Comment: "Незнакомой" — отглагольное прилагательное, образованное от непереходного глагола, пишется слитно, кроме тех случаев, когда "в качестве пояснительных слов выступают местоимения и наречия, начинающиеся с ни, или сочетания далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не" (Розенталь).

Comment: А оно точно отглагольное? Если так, то да, согласен.
Но что-то я сомневаюсь... 
Я-то писал в расчете на обычное прилагательное. 

Но вообще причатия и прилагательные типа неустановленный, неузнанный, незнакомый и т.д. всегда вызывают вопросы. Очень уж разные значения у них при раздельном и слитном написании... Как бы не от смысла завиело...

Comment: Добрый вечер, я сегодня прошла парочку диктантов от Грамоты.ру и, пожалуй, была в шоке от ошибок, взявшихся из ниоткуда. Может, следует ещё раз написать в службу с просьбой о перепроверке, потому что прошло уже 7 лет, а ничего не изменилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виктор, там масса ошибок в диктантах. Об этом им регулярно напоминают, но воз и ныне там.
Конкретно по вопросу.
(Не)знакомый - прилагательное, на причастие как-то совсем не похоже. 
Но в данном контексте выступает в грамматической роли, более свойственой причастию, поскольку присоединяет конструкцию, близкую к причастному обороту (т.н. "распространённое определение"). Некогда сейчас искать источники, но рискну предположить, что правило о раздельном написания НЕ с причастием при наличии зависимых слов можно распространиить и на этот случай, исходя из логики самого правила: при наличии зависимых слов обычно идет отрицание значения (качества), а не утверждение нового, противоположного. Впрочем, правило это не императивное, допускаю, что автор может его нарушить исходя из смысла своего высказывания. И "незнакомый с кем/чем" - как раз тот пограничный случай, когда возможно новое качество "незнакомство", а не отричание знакомства. 
Интересно, что в переводах Борхеса написание как раз слитное, но это уже от переводчика.
http://ezolib.ru/2833.html

Но в диктанте я всё-таки предпочел бы раздельное написание. Исходя из контекста и логики проверяющих.

А вообще я против использования в подобных целях переводных текстов.

Comment: Спасибо. Что касается различий в слитном-раздельном написании НЕ с разными частями речи, то об этом я читал у Розенталя. Там приводятся примеры такого написания в зависимости от смысла (Эта книга неинтересная, т.е. скучная.- Эта книга не интересная (отрицается интересность книги, но не утверждается, что она скучна).

Comment: А вот насчет пояснительных слов у прилагательных, которые влияли бы на правописание частицы НЕ, нигде не читал. Вспоминается только у того же Розенталя правило, касающееся прилагательных на -МЫЙ (кстати, незнакомый сюда тоже относится). Но Розенталь разрешает написать НЕ с таким прилагательным раздельно, если в качестве зависимого слова выступает т.н. творительный инструментальный (невидимые на небе звезды ,НО не видимые невооруженным глазом звезды)

Comment: Есть у Розенталя объяснение. См. Справочник по правописанию и стилистике, § 66 Правописание не с именами прилагательными, п. 10.

Различается написание не с отглагольными прилагательными на -мый и с причастиями на -мый: при наличии пояснительных слов первые пишутся слитно (как и отыменные прилагательные), вторые – раздельно, например: а) необитаемый с давних пор остров, нерастворимые в воде кристаллы, неразличимые в темноте фигуры людей; б) не посещаемые охотниками заповедники, не читаемые неспециалистами журналы, не любимый матерью ребенок.

Comment: Марина, Вы, конечно, обратили внимание, что в разделе б) во всех приведенных примерах в качестве пояснительных слов выступают существительные в творительном падеже, то есть тот же творительный инструментальный, о котором я упоминал в комментарии. В противном случае эти слова будут писаться слитно: нечитаемый в темноте текст, нелюбимая осенней порой погода

Comment: В примерах б) даны причастия на -мый. 
 "Причастиями они являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется творительный падеж действующего лица, реже творительный орудия (текст, не читаемый мной); при наличии других пояснительных слов они становятся прилагательными". (Грамота, вопрос-ответ № 202001). 

Виктор, вы что хотите понять? Есть ли ошибка в диктанте? Есть. Сформулировать правило? Оно большое и сложное )

Comment: Я хочу понять, допустил ли я ошибку, написав "...эпохи, незнакомой с нашим понятием о плагиате..."

Comment: Не допустили )

Answer (score 1):

Если у слова есть синомим, его можно заменить на похожее, например, незнакомый - незнакомец, какой-то, чужой,аноним, имярек, некий, и т.д., то слово пишентся слитно. Если же по смыслу оно не подзразумевает замены на данные слова, то есть несёт другой смысл, другую нагрузку, то пишется раздельно.

Comment: Что? Новые правила русского языка?

Comment: Почему новое? Старое, универсальное, но только для существительных, прилагательных или наречий на О(Е). Привычнее оно звучит так: можно заменить синонимом или близким по смыслу выражением - пишу слитно. А со словами на -мый (прилагательное? причастие?) все гораздо сложнее, правило просто огромное. Согласна с комментариями Марины.

Answer (score 0):

С некоторого времени пишу эти диктанты. Получается хорошо, хоть и небезупречно. Чтобы были ошибки, не помню, всегда удовлетворяло объяснение того, в чём я ошибался, хотя не исключаю. Все мы люди, включая тех, кто составляет данные диктанты.
Спасибо, что вынесли на обсуждение этот случай. Я тоже написал слитно:(

Comment: И Вам спасибо, что приняли участие в обсуждении. Кстати, Евгений, с удовольствием знакомлюсь с Вашим сайтом о "Русском медвежонке". Там много любопытного, так что советую всем нашим форумчанам его посетить

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв о моём сайте!

Comment: А ссылку можно?